# JsViews: Converter before helper function in data-link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender, jsviews

Using [JsViews](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews) is it possible to have a converter precede a helper function in a data-link property? Somehow like this..

```
<div data-link="{myConverter:~myFunction('param1'):}"></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you want the converter to convert the value of the `param1` field of your data object, and then pass it to the `myConverter` function, then no. The converter will process the result of the expression `~myFunction(...)`.

But you can create an equivalent helper function to your converter, and then chain the helpers:

```
<div data-link="~myFunction(~myConvert(param1))></div>"
```

BTW this will be data linked so that it updates when the param1 field changes. - I'm not sure if you meant to put quotes around 'param1'. If 'param1' is a string literal you are passing in, then data-linking to it won't have any reason to update, so you could just write:

```
<div>{{:~myFunction(~myConvert('param1'))}}</div>
```