# JsViews: data-linking with a helper function

Tags: list, data-binding, helper, jsrender, jsviews

I am using JsViews to render a list, but first passing the list through a helper function like so:

```
<ul>
  {^{for ~filter(list, 'xyz')}}
    <li>...</li>
  {{/for}}
</ul>
```

Where `filter` creates a new list based on `list` with only some of the original elements  based on the filtering criteria.  The trouble is, when I update `list`:

```
$.observable(data.list).insert(list.length, { ... });
```

the `{^{for ...}}` does not get re-evaluated.  However, if I remove the filter, changing the `{^{for ...}` to this:

```
{^{for list}}
  ...
{{/for}}
```

Then everything works as expected.  Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?  It seems JsViews should be able to do what I want, because this answer is similar enough: [JsViews: Converter before helper function in data-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172541/jsviews-converter-before-helper-function-in-data-link).

Comment: Now I'm wondering: is there a way to get this to work or am I going to have to invalidate part of the view to get it to re-render? $.view(this).___(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jrop: For now, your workaround makes sense. Your scenario relates to some future features of JsObservable, for having linked arrays with a transformation (e.g. filter, sort, or page) defining the relationship between the source and target arrays. The target would raise array change events whenever its content changes as a result of observable changes in the source.

Current observable APIs should make this possible to implement today, but a semi-declarative approach out of the box, in JsViews, is not yet available.

Another approach could be a derived `{{for_with_filtering ...}}` tag, derived from `{{for}}` but where you can optionally include a filter: `{{forplus list filter=~filter('xyz')}}`. I'll be posting a related sample very soon showing a {{for}} which lets you set the start and integers for the iteration. (`{{for_range ...}}`).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a workaround to this, although I sure would like @BorisMoore to weigh in on this!

The solution is to update the view manually, because the filtered data does not `===` the bound data (I guess).  So instead of doing:

```
$.observable(data.list).insert(data.list.length, item);
```

I changed to:

```
data.list.push({...});
$.view('#target', true, 'data').refresh();
```

Where `#target` is the selector of the target `<div>` that holds the rendered content.

Again, I really would be glad if @BorisMoore could weigh in on this, as this solution refreshes a chunk of the view instead of incrementally adding an item (from what I understand).